# Resources for learning about digital cameras technical design?

Tags: dslr, lens-design

I would like to learn more about the design of digital cameras in general, and DSLR in particular, from optics to sensors to mounts.

Do you know any up-to-date resources (other than Wikipedia) where I can find some information about those subjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website [Cambridge in Colour](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials.htm) has a series of tutorials that cover everything from camera basics up through some more advanced topics on optics and sensors. Their focus is on providing education to help improve photographic skill, but they lay a good technical foundation in the process.

Answer (score 4):

This site right here! Stack Exchange sites aren't really very well suited to "list o' resources" questions. Google is better for that, and always will be. But Photo-SE is well-suited to *being* such a resource. In fact, that's exactly what it's for.

If you have actual questions about specific things which aren't answered here already, please ask them (as individual new questions), and you should get good answers.

Comment: The great @mattdm, making one of those fatal mistakes he is so well known for pointing out in others! Shame! Should really be a comment. ;P

Comment: Ha! I started it as a comment, but then I realized that the first part ("_this_ site is a great resource") actually directly answers the question. So there. :-P

Comment: I actually agree with mattdm on that... his reply directly answers the question.